# unsupported operand type(s) in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, floating-point, decimal

Say I have a panda dataframe and want to print rows with two particular columns (`Score` and `Score1`) that have different values. 
I am running on python 3.6

I tried

```
print(Data[round(Data['Score'],4)!=round(Data['Score1'],4)])
```

and got this error:

> unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'float'

I also tried

```
from decimal import *
print(Data[Decimal(round(Data['Score'],4))!=round(Data['Score1'],4)])
```

and get:

> conversion from Series to Decimal is not supported

---

```
Here is some sample data
              Score             Score1
0        0.00187718  0.001877000000000
1       0.000184217  0.000184000000000
2       0.000502648  0.000503000000000
3          0.185124  0.185124000000000
4        3.3589e-05  0.000034000000000
5        0.00156229  0.001562000000000
6        6.4937e-05  0.000065000000000
7       4.87503e-05  0.000049000000000
8        0.00215561  0.002156000000000
9       3.22308e-05  0.000044000000000
10      3.70668e-05  0.000037000000000
11      0.000100837  0.000101000000000
12      7.91073e-05  0.000079000000000
13       0.00424232  0.004232000000000
14      6.80564e-06  0.000007000000000
15       0.00928687  0.009287000000000
```

My solution for now is to output the dataframe to csv and reload the csv into python. It looks good to me. Knowing that its definitely not a smart way, I am going with it given my tight timeline.

Comment: either `Data[Decimal(round(Data['Score'],4))!=Decimal(round(Data['Score1'],4))]`

or `Data[Float(round(Data['Score'],4))!=Float(round(Data['Score1'],4))]`

Comment: Can you provide the complete traceback and a [MCVE]? I don't see any multiplication in the code that's claiming you tried to multiply a `Decimal` by a `float`. If I explicitly do something like `round(d('1.334442'), 4) != round(1.334442, 4)` is, just returns `True` for me, which is sub-optimal (`float` doesn't represent `1.3344` precisely, so it's not actually equal), but doesn't raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some other common approaches for comparing floating values. They are not equivalent to what you implemented but should still be good in many scenarios.

Using native `pandas`:

```
selected = data[(data["Score"]-data["Score1"]).abs() >= 1e-4]
print(selected)
```

Using `numpy.isclose`:

```
import numpy as np

selected = data[~np.isclose(data["Score"], data["Score1"], 0, 1e-4)]
print(selected)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are comparing two numbers (float point number rounded to a certain decimal place).
I think you can try this (compare a with b)

```
a = 0.00542
b = 0.00534
decimal_place = 4 #or any place you want
round(a-b, decimal_place) # if this is zero, consider a and b as the same
```

Since I don't know what kind of data you have, I cannot implement things in pandas for you. This is what I come up with when seeing your question. Hope that it will help you out.

Update after getting the data file:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "datafile"

df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace = True)
print(df)
print(df.columns)
df["Compare"] = (round(df["Score"] - df["Score1"], 6) == 0)
print(df)
```

Somehow, my code works smoothly (after copying your data into a file named "datafile"). I plan to run your code and find out why.

Unfortunately, after plugging your code into my code, I still cannot find why it did not work out. It seems just fine to run:

```
import pandas as pd

filename = "datafile"

df = pd.read_csv(filename, delim_whitespace = True)
print(df)
print(df.columns)
print(round(df['Score'],4)!=round(df['Score1'],4))
#print(df[round(df['Score'],4)!=round(df['Score1'],4)])
#I delete the df[] around the round...4)
```

Here is the output

```
0     False
1     False
2     False
3     False
4     False
5     False
6     False
7     False
8     False
9     False
10    False
11    False
12    False
13    False
14    False
15    False
dtype: bool
```

I guessed you did not read in the file in a correct way. I would suggest printing out the data frame to see why.
Good luck with that!

Comment: If you could provide me with a sample (a part of your dataframe), I can delve into it and help you out.

Comment: Thanks. I cannot subtract either. Same error for subtraction "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'decimal.Decimal'"

Comment: Just added some sample data